# How to update NotifyIcon and ContentControl with CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have Modal Window : ContentControl (User Control) inside MainWindow and NotifyIcon.
I change CurrentCulture with events handled on radiobuttons.

Like this:

```WPF
// Initialization
public string LangSwitch { get; private set; } = "";

// Language switch method
private void OnEnglishRadioButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LangSwitch = "en-US";
    Close();
}
```

App.xaml.cs code:

```C#
public static void ToggleLanguage(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var window = (MainWindow) sender;
   if (window == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(window.LangSwitch)) return;

   window.Closed -= ToggleLanguage;
   window.Close();

   var language = window.LangSwitch;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
   Settings.Default.LanguageCode = language;
   Settings.Default.Save(); 

   window = new MainWindow();
   window.Show();
}
```

The MainWindow "refreshes", all the text get CurrentCulture and updating to it. But my Modal Window and NotifyIcon get CurrentCulture, but not updating they UI.

If I restart application, than they update.

I'm tried to refresh my ModalWindow Frame. Initializing new NotifyIcon and dispose previous. Set Frame content to default page (First page). Nothing helped. What I need to do?

GitHub [link](https://github.com/Real-Time-Messenger/FlyMessenger-desktopclient) to the project: https://github.com/Real-Time-Messenger/FlyMessenger-desktopclient

*NotifyIcon is in FlyMessenger/Core/Utils/NotifyIconManager*

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't the entire app just using the windows culture the user has chosen? Which you could read and apply before building any ui.

Comment: @Andy I need to change language at runtime. Like Telegram. Not all people sit in their language on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have another solution.

I restarting proccess with this code in App.xaml.cs:

```WPF
var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
Process.Start(processName + ".exe");
Current.Shutdown();
```

This solution is not best and have a lot of minuses, but it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).